# bottle write to page content from python code block

Tags: python, templates, bottle

is it possible to write in to the page content from within a [python code block in a Bottle SimpleTemplate file](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#embedded-python-code)?

e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <%
      # A block of python code
      basket = [1,2,3]
      print("<ul>")    # this prints on the server console, not the rendered page
      for item in basket:
        print("<li>" + str(item) + "</li>")

      print("</ul>")
    %>      
</body>
</html>
```

I know i could use the specific syntax for loops in this case, but i'd like to know an alternative for use in more complex cases:

```
<ul>
  % for item in basket:
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  % end
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
%result = ''
<body>
    <%
      # A block of python code
      basket = [1,2,3]
      result+="<ul>"    # this prints on the server console, not the rendered page
      for item in basket:
        result+="<li>" + str(item) + "</li>"

      result+="</ul>"
    %>      
{{result}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks the best workaround, thank you for posting!

Answer (score -1):

No, I'm afraid **it's not directly possible.** And even if it were, **you probably shouldn't do it.**

The cleanest designs keep their logic in the server code; templates are merely for presentation.

For example, [this templating tutorial](https://pwp.stevecassidy.net/bottle/templating.html) says:

> In general we'd like to separate the HTML content from the program logic.

You said:

> I know i could use the specific syntax for loops in this case, but i'd like to know an alternative for use in more complex cases

I'm curious: why are you looking for an alternative? You allude to "more complex cases," but your example is just a loop. If you show us an example which you think can't be handled cleanly the standard way, perhaps we can help you with that specific case.